# Trying to send an INT via XBee Arduino

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am trying to simply send a "1" or a "2" via Xbee & Arduino. My Arduino TX is Serial.print ing a "1" or a "2" successfully but the RX is not receiving the same.

TX:

```
void buttonBring()
{
  delay(75);tone(speakerpin,660,300);
  delay(75);tone(speakerpin,330,300);
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
  //Serial.println("Button B is Ringing");
  Serial.write("2");
  delay(600);

}
```

RX: The received Value is

```
126
0
6
129
0
0
44
2
50
30
```

RX Code:

```
void loop() {
  if (xBee.available()) {
    byte bell = xBee.read();
    Serial.println(bell, DEC);
  }
```

I would like to just receive a 1 or a 2 or even an A or a B so that the receiver can make decisions or use a switch case, but the rx needs to be yes or no format. How am I messing this up?

Answer (score 0):

The receiving XBee is configured for API mode instead of "AT mode", and you're seeing a 0x81 packet of the received data.  The 126 (0x7E) is the start of the frame, 6 the length, 129 the type (0x81), the double zeros are the sending address (0x0000 = coordinator).  I'm not sure about the 44 (0x2C) or 2 (0x02) since I don't have the frame format handy, but the payload of 50 (0x32 or the character '2') looks good.  The 30 is a checksum for the frame.

Read through the XBee documentation from Digi for details on frame formats if you want to explore API mode more.  If you're just using two radios, "AT mode" will be easier to use.  It will be as if you just have a serial cable connecting the two devices.